"We couldn't retrieve or load the information on the field" in retrieve call
I'm trying to retrieve a FlexiPage using the CLI called Contact_Record_Page_V2. We've been cleaning out some fields lately, and that page now seems to be corrupt. I assume it's trying to look for a field that no longer exists. I figured I could edit the metadata in VS Code and rip out that dependency. When I ran the command sf project start retrieve -m FlexiPage:Contact_Record_Page_V2, I got the error (with IDs changed):
Unable to retrieve file for id 0M07V0000000000 of type FlexiPage. Something went wrong. We couldn't retrieve or load the information on the field: Record.00NUx0000000000. 

Any idea how to still retrieve this metadata? Everything I've seen is about deploying, not retrieving. I'm imagining, if I can get a hold of the XML file, I could fix the problem.
